# best way to upload array buffer (audio buffer) with ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a audio buffer which looks like this : [float32Array[largeSize], float32Array[largeSize]].

and I am trying to figure out how best to upload this to my express/node server.

The way I am thinking of doing this is like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/uploadTrackOne',
        data: {buffer : JSON.stringify(MYAUDIOBUFFERS},
        dataType: "buffer"
     });
```

Is this the correct way to go about this?

If the buffer gets long enough I get the following error:
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length

And it seems like on such a large buffer, JSON.stringy is very slow, so I'm thinking maybe Im not doing this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as it turned out with XMLHttpRequest2, its pretty easy to send raw binary data, no need to stringify. This fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

You should look into "chunking": Split the buffer into smaller parts, and then upload the parts one by one. Here are two examples (for uploading files):

- http://mylinuxtechcorner.blogspot.no/2015/03/upload-large-files-on-web-using.html (using jQuery and `$.ajax({ ...` ).
- http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/n7psA/ (using `XMLHttpRequest`).

Your server then needs to put the pieces back together again.